# Change route template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a controller which is placed in `/users/account_controller.rb`

The route for that is: `resources :account controller: 'users/account'`

And in the view I have the `account` folder under `view` not under `users`

Now when I try to access `new on account` is looking for the template `users/account/new` how can I point that to `account/new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably may have two options(could be more)

1.Move the `account_controller.rb` from the `users` and put it under `app/controllers` directory. And change your route to `resources :account`.

OR

2.Just Place your `account` folder in `views` under `users`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to render a specific view in a non-RESTFUL manner, you can just tell rails what to render at the end of your method:

```
#account_controller.rb
def new
.
.
render 'account/new'
end
```